# Lie bracket of gradients

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Related to [Why symplectic geometry gives Poisson geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255034/why-symplectic-geometry-gives-poisson-geometry)

Is there any common use for the Lie bracket of the gradients of two functions? That is, $[\nabla f, \nabla g]$?

Here, $\nabla f$ denotes the vector field gotten by "raising the index" from $df$. In other words, $(\nabla f)(g) = m(df, dg)$, where $m$ is the Riemannian metric on some manifold.

Comment: If the gradient is a $1$-form, then how do you define the Lie bracket of $1$-forms? And if you use a Riemannian metric to turn $1$-forms into vector fields, then these two will commute.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev That doesn't seem to be true; take $f = x, g = x^2$ with the usual 1-dimensional metric. Then $\nabla f = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \nabla g = 2x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, [\nabla f, \nabla g] = -2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Indeed. But if the gradients are linearly independent, they can be seen as coordinate vector fields, and then they do commute.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev That still isn't true; take $f = x, g = x^2 + y$, and the usual metric. Then $\nabla f = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \nabla g = 2x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, which are generally linearly independent, and the Lie bracket is the same. Linear independence is not enough; the vector fields will generally not commute.